# Como posso apagar registros do Regedit que no diretório contenham a serial "SID" por um arquivo .bat

Tags: cmd, bat

Estou tentando criar um arquivo **.bat** que apague registros específicos dentro do Regedit que funcione em qualquer computador. Quando tento apagar os registros dentro do diretório (*Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\bam\State\UserSettings\S-1-5*...), ele mostra um grande número que quando fui pesquisar mais a fundo, descobri que essa serial é denominada "**SID**" e ela muda de computador para computador.

Gostaria de ter um código que pegasse o suposto "**SID**" e o acrescentasse na linha de código.
Um exemplo disso seria:

*REG DELETE HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\bam\State\UserSettings\%SID%*

Durante minhas tentativas, percebi que não era possível e teria que escrever um código/script que pegasse o **SID** com "*whoami /user*" e colocasse-o junto do "*REG DELETE*", mas atualmente não possuo capacidade para fazer isso e estou aqui procurando por ajuda.

Comment: Por curiosidade qual o motivo de você querer apagar essa chave? Pelo que eu vi ela se refere a monitoramente de processos de fundo...

Comment: Depois que a chave é apagada ela deve ser recriada?

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
@echo off

net session >nul 2>&1 || (powershell start -verb runas '"%~0"' &exit /b)


for /f "tokens=2 Delims=," %%a in ('whoami /user /fo csv /nh') do (
                                                                   echo \Registry\Machine\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\bam\State\UserSettings\%%~a [1 8 17] >"%temp%\ArquivoTemp.txt"
                                                                   regini "%temp%\ArquivoTemp.txt"
                                                                   reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\bam\State\UserSettings\%%~a" /va /f
                                                                  )

del /q "%temp%\ArquivoTemp.txt"
```